# Python: Parent and Child responding to child-specific changes in boolean values. Why is this happening?

Tags: python, boolean

EDIT: Case closed. See the chosen answer below for a solution (thanks rnorris!)

The questions asked are below.

---

I have gotten some insight on my question, and I now believe that the question is more about how to set things equal to each other in Python, but only in values. From my understanding, I am running into problems because I want to first set the children equal to their parent, and then change them as necessary. The problem is that when I say

```
child = parent
```

It makes them refer to the same space in memory, and thus any changes to child values become changes to parent values. Is there a way to set child equal to parent while still allowing their values to be edited separately?

The original question is below.

---

This is another question about my project with booleans. I am trying to figure out why my project is behaving in a strange way. My apologies for a very long question, I hope you are able to help me!

My project is to model a graph search, and my problem is with the parents and children. How it works is that there are up to four possible actions to be taken on the parent to produce a new child node: flipping 'farmer' from true to false (or vice versa), and then flipping both farmer and any of three other bools, wolf, sheep, and cabbage, but only if they are equal to farmer (ie. if wolf and farmer are both true, then flip both of them to make a new child). In the case of my initial parent node, all four bools are false, so there should be four child nodes made, one for each event.

```
#boolfliptest

class node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.farmer, self.wolf, self.sheep, self.cabbage = False, False, False, False
        self.parent = None
        self.cost = 0

parent = node()
fchild = node()
schild = node()
wchild = node()
cchild = node()

fchild = parent
fchild.farmer = (True, False)[fchild.farmer]
fchild.parent = parent
fchild.cost += 1

if(parent.farmer == parent.wolf):
    wchild = parent
    wchild.farmer != wchild.farmer
    wchild.wolf != wchild.wolf
    wchild.parent = parent
    wchild.cost += 1

if(parent.farmer == parent.sheep):
    schild = parent
    schild.farmer != schild.farmer
    schild.sheep != schild.sheep
    schild.parent = parent
    schild.cost += 1

if(parent.farmer == parent.cabbage):
    cchild = parent
    cchild.farmer != cchild.farmer
    cchild.cabbage != wchild.cabbage
    cchild.parent = parent
    cchild.cost += 1


print parent.farmer, parent.wolf, parent.sheep, parent.cabbage
print fchild.farmer, fchild.wolf, fchild.sheep, fchild.cabbage
print wchild.farmer, wchild.wolf, wchild.sheep, wchild.cabbage
print schild.farmer, schild.wolf, schild.sheep, schild.cabbage
print cchild.farmer, cchild.wolf, cchild.sheep, cchild.cabbage
```

This indeed happens, as I am using a print line to print out the four boolean values for the parent and the four children. They should come out as follows:

```
    False False False False #parent
    True  False False False #farmer flip only
    True  True  False False #farmer and wolf flip
    True  False True  False #farmer and sheep flip
    True  False False True  #farmer and cabbage flip
```

But instead I only get this:

```
 % python boolfliptest.py
    False False False False
    False False False False
    False False False False
    False False False False
    False False False False
```

I thought maybe I was using a poor method to toggle bools, and apparently I was, as the original method

```
schild.farmer != schild.farmer #taken from above
```

did not work. I replaced just the fchild flip statement with this new way of toggling bools

```
fchild.farmer = (True, False)[fchild.farmer]
```

And I did get better results, but not what I expected. The result was this:

```
% python boolfliptest.py
True False False False
True False False False
False False False False
False False False False
False False False False
```

The fchild (second on the list) did flip correctly, like I expected, but so too did the parent node, which should have remained all false!

I tried one other thing. I commented out the fchild.farmer bool flip line, and instead used that new method with the wchild bools. ie:

```
if(parent.farmer == parent.wolf):
    wchild = parent
    wchild.farmer = (True, False)[wchild.farmer]
    wchild.wolf = (True, False)[wchild.wolf]
    wchild.parent = parent
    wchild.cost += 1
```

This result was equally confusing. The wchild flipping worked correctly, but it was copied for both the fchild and the parent, neither of which should have changed.

```
% python boolfliptest.py
True True False False
True True False False
True True False False
False False False False
False False False False
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here? Why are the bools so odd?

Comment: You use both `= !foo` and `!= foo` in several places. I think that you want to use `= !foo` in all of those places. `!= foo` does a comparison, the result of which is immediately thrown away.

Comment: `!wchild.farmer` isn't valid Python syntax, so this code can't run in the first place. What is your actual code?

Comment: Also, `schild.farmer != schild.farmer` _is_ valid code, but it's just a fancy way to write `False`, so… what are you _trying_ to do there?

Comment: That was my mistake, I posted a flawed version of the code. The correction has been applied. I thought that foo != foo would flip the value, but apparently not, and as you said, foo = !foo is indeed invalid python syntax.

I intended to make the bool value flip from True to False, and I found a method that works to do that (as mentioned above), but it seems to change more than it should, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here, one of which is that you're creating all of your nodes like so:

```
parent = node()
fchild = node()
schild = node()
wchild = node()
cchild = node()
```

But later in your code, you have lines such as:

```
wchild = parent
```

I suspect that this is (part of) your problem.  Because of the way variables work in Python, now the variables `wchild` and `parent` both point to the same object.  When you do comparisons and operate on the fields of `wchild`, you're now also operating on the fields of `parent`.

As an example:

```
parent = node()
wchild = node()
parent.farmer = True
wchild = parent
if wchild.farmer:
  print "Farmer"
```

Should print out "Farmer".

Additionally, a better way to do negations in Python is like so:

```
wchild.wolf = not wchild.wolf
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: to answer the comment a bit more clearly: if you want to copy the values from parent to child, you can define a method for the `node` class like this:

```
def copy(self, child_node):
  child_node.farmer = self.farmer
```

and so on for the other fields.  That way, you can create a copy like so:

```
parent = node()
child = node()
parent.farmer = True
parent.copy(child)
```

Now `child.farmer` will be `True`, and you can change it without changing `parent.farmer`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I not used to Python yet, so I'm not yet adept in all of its peculiarities. Is there a way then to make the children initially the same value as the parent node without making them actually point to the same place?

Comment: Well, for each child, you can simply say that `child.farmer = parent.farmer` and similar for the other fields, but a better way would be to define a `copy` method of the `node` class that takes a child as an argument and equates their fields in a manner similar to `child.farmer = parent.farmer`.  I'll edit my answer to give an example.

Comment: Your answer has helped me to reach the next level. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome!  As a bonus, you can use the `is` comparator to see if two objects point to the same memory address.  It can be tempting for newcomers to use `is` instead of `==` when making comparisons, but know that `is` will return `False` in some cases where `==` will return `True`.